# What is javascript/typescript equivalent of this python function?

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

I couldn't convert this syntax to js or ts:

```py
    def get_index(self):
        path = self.get_request_path()
        if "/_async_search" in path and "/_search":
            # no index we wildcard
            return next((sub_part for sub_part in path.split("/") if sub_part != ""), "*")
        return None
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried or what you're stuck on?

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but I found this article: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3209651/how-to-convert-python-to-javascript-and-back-again.html

Comment: Yeah I used online py->js compilers but it didn't work. 
Basically conversion of the function I don't know what "in and" means and next part.

Comment: `and "/_search"` is a useless expression.  Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yeah I thought so too I guess it's something similar to this in js `("/_async_search" in path && '/_search')` but was not sure if it means something different in python syntax

Answer (score 1):

I think the main complication to do the javascript translation of your python code is to lazy load the list returned by `path.split("/")` like it's done in your python code.

For that, you can use a generator function like the following:

```
function* first_substring(path) {
  for(substring of path.split("/")){
    if(substring !== ""){
        yield substring;
    }
    else{
        yield "*";
    }
  }
}
```

Then your javascript translation would be something like:

```
function get_index(){
    const path = this.get_request_path();

    if(path.indexOf("/_async_search") !== -1 && "/_search"){
        return first_substring(path).next().value;
    }

    return None

}
```